# Need help working out update statement with 2 criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I have 3 tables that are all linked but via poor planning the data and migration has never been completed.

I have 3 tables.

```
1. User
- It contains an email address and a PK of userID

2.Contact
-It contains a c_usedid , email address,roleid,systemcode and a field for d_userid and userid

3. contactuser
This is a linking table. It auto increments its PK (d_userid) and has userid (fk) and systemcode.
```

Stay with me.

I need to run an update on contact that fills in the d_userid where userid and systemcode are both equal to the same value in contactuser.

Anyone have an ideas? I tried a merge into but since there might be multiple rows (multiple roles!) in each system it wouldnt allow me to execute the code. I am using SQL Server 2012 if it matters.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, this sounds like the update that you want:

```
update c
    set d_userid = cu.d_userid
    from contact c join
         contactuser cu
         on c.userid = cu.userid and c.systemcode = cu.systemcode;
```